# Python turtle, delete line

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Hi i try to learn how to use turtle in python, I did the following code for paint my initials(V T) but I don't know how to rid off the black line.

```py
import turtle

def draw_myname():
     window = turtle.Screen()
     window.bgcolor("red")

    #Create the V letter - Draw V
     vita = turtle.Turtle()
     vita.shape("turtle")
     vita.color("yellow")
     vita.speed(2)
     vita.right(75)
     vita.forward(100)
     vita.left(150)
     vita.forward(100)
     vita.right(75)

     #Create the T letter - Draw T
     vita = turtle.Turtle()
     vita.goto(100,0)
     vita.shape("turtle")
     vita.color("blue")
     vita.forward(5)
     vita.forward(100)
     vita.back(50)
     vita.right(90)
     vita.forward(100)

     window.exitonclick()
draw_myname()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set [`turtle.up()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/turtle.html#turtle.up) so it doesn't draw a line while moving. Add `vita.up()` before moving and when you're ready to draw add `vita.down()`.

```
#Create the T letter - Draw T
vita = turtle.Turtle()
vita.up() #add this
vita.goto(100,0)
vita.down() #add this
vita.shape("turtle")
vita.color("blue")
vita.forward(5)
vita.forward(100)
vita.back(50)
vita.right(90)
vita.forward(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers that were posted, another approach could be:

You don't have to redefine the turtle (name the turtle, change its shape and stuff) but you do have to change its color.

Also, if you wanted to erase the black line, the method I use is to change the color of the turtle to the background color and overlap the black line.

Answer (score 1):

Using python 3.8, with turtle.
My experience is that obtaining background, after setting the pen color, using color(col), returns col in both of the following cases:

```
foreground, background = color()
foreground = pencolor()
background = fillcolor()
```

My only success in "erasing a line", for example, to replace a thicker line with a thinner line of the same color was to use the following code, using "white" explicitly as the background:

```
side = 100
def move_x():
    """ Change current and subsequent lines to a thinner line
    """
    foreground = pencolor()
    background = "white"
    print(f"foreground:{foreground} background:{background}")
    color(background)       # Erase previous line
    backward(side)
    color(foreground)
    t = width()
    t -= 1
    if t < 1:
        t = 1
    width(t)
    forward(side)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `penup()`. Or, in your case, `vita.penup()`.

Comment: This is a simple answer, I know.